# Convert JSON string to "Object.class"

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am currently trying to use Jackson to turn an object into a JSON string this was easily done by

```
public byte[] toJSON(Object obj) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper map = new ObjectMapper();
        return map.writeValueAsString(obj).getBytes();
    }
```

Where i run into trouble is when i was to take the array of bytes and turn them into an Object.  Currently i have:

```
public Object toObject(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectMapper map = new ObjectMapper();
    return (Object)map.readValue(bytes, Object.class);
}
```

I successfully convert an object to a JSON string but the Object returned from the toObject method is always a LinkedHashMap instead of the object that was initially turned into the JSON string.

Sorry if i did a poor job communicating my problem but ill try to sum it up simply.  I want my code to be able to do the following:

```
MyClass someObject = new MyClass();
String json = toJSON(someObject);
Object tempObject = toObject(json);
MyClass sameObject = (MyClass) tempObject;
```

this code currently throws the following:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.MyClass
```

Any help on the matter would be appreciated!

Comment: why are you returning a object, instead try `return map.readValue(bytes, YourObject.class);`

Comment: Create an String from your bytes and try Jackson on resulted String.

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting an `Object`, so Jackson creates one `Object` it knows it can create: a `Map`. JSON array would become a `List` and so on.

If you want `MyClass`, you must request it explicitly, or, if you want a general-purpose serialization/deserialization, for inclusion of type identifier, as suggested by @csd.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm a little confused why you need to deal with `byte[]` at all.  `objectMapper.writeVaueAsString(obj)` gives you a perfectly good `String` with the JSON representation of your object.  If you need to convert to `byte[]` then you need to convert back to `String` before calling `readValue`.

But putting that aside for now, let's suppose you've got that `String` containing the JSON.  By default, Jackson isn't smart enough to know (from looking at the JSON alone) what Java class to instantiate when you call `readValue`.  In your example, you pass in `Object.class`, which isn't very helpful for Jackson since EVERY object in Java extends from `Object`.  So in that case, it chooses its built-in default, which is to build a `Map` (in particular, a `LinkedHashMap`) with keys and values as listed in the JSON.

As one commenter pointed out, you can give Jackson a hint and pass `MyClass.class` as the second parameter to `readValue` (instead of `Object.class`).  If you did that, then JSON will create an instance of `MyClass` at the beginning of `readValue`.  And when it sees something like "`foo: 43`" in the JSON, it'll try to find a field or setter (i.e. `public int foo;` or `public void setFoo(int f)`) in `MyClass` and set the value accordingly.

If you don't know ahead of time what type of object it is (i.e. what value to pass as the second parameter to `readValue`) then there are other options.  One of example of this is to require that your JSON objects have a `class` property that Jackson will use as a hint for which type of Java object to create.  Here's what that code might look like:

```
// This annotation tells Jackson to include the class name as
// a "class" property when *writing* JSON.
@JsonTypeInfo(include=As.PROPERTY, use=Id.CLASS, property="class")
public class MyClass {
    public int foo;
}
```

This will make your JSON look like this:

```
{ "class":"MyClass", foo:0 }
```

Then in your code to read the object, do this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.enableDefaultTypingAsProperty(DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT, "class");
// Note Object.class as second parameter.  Jackson will find the "class"
// property in the JSON and use it to determine which class to make.
MyClass foo = (MyClass) objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Object.class);
```

Comment: One can also use `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes()` in cases where bytes are needed (or just write to `OutputStream`)