# convert JSON String to Object.class and use instanceof to determine actual class

Tags: java, json

I've got a question similar to the one asked here:

[Convert JSON string to “Object.class”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418737/convert-json-string-to-object-class)

I'd like to do this *without*

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include=As.PROPERTY, use=Id.CLASS, property="class")
```

on all the classes I wish to serialize/deserialize to/from JSON.

I'd like to do something like:

```
Object o = mapper.readValue(*a JSON string*, Object.class);

if (o instance of *foo.bar.SomeClass*){

    foo.bar.SomeClass fb = (foo.bar.SomeClass)o

                   *or*

    foo.bar.SomeClass fb = mapper.readValue(*a JSON string*, foo.bar.SomeClass);    }
```

Is that at all possible?